# Azure azcopy fails after AAD success authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azcopy

I am trying to use azcopy tool from Ubuntu 20.04 to upload file to Azure Blob.

I am authenticated with AAD and SP:

```
export AZCOPY_SPA_CLIENT_SECRET="12345678"
azcopy login --service-principal  --application-id abc --tenant-id=xyz
```

Here I get auth success:

```
INFO: SPN Auth via secret succeeded.
```

However when I run:

```
azcopy copy './myfile' 'https://mystorageacc.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myfile'
```

I get this error:

```
failed to perform copy command due to error: Login Credentials missing. No SAS token or OAuth token is present and the resource is not public
```

Obviously the AAD service principals are in the role 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' of the storage account.

What is wrong? thanks

Comment: Can you try the fix from this link - " interactive AD login seems to succeed. But if I try to logout immediately, the logout fails. All other commands (e.g., azcopy copy) also fail, indicating that the login did not actually succeed." - <https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/452>

Comment: ok. I do not get anymore the error by doing the following however the file is not actually transferred as I do not see it in the Portal:  keyctl new_session
sleep 1
azcopy login --identity --identity-resource-id ${identity_id}
keyctl show
azcopy cp '${blob_endpoint}/artifact.tar' '/opt/artifact.tar'

Comment: ok I'll add it to the answer section as resolution

Comment: well It is not a real resolution. As I said, the file is not uploaded.

Comment: Is the copy failure producing the same error or different?

Comment: It states successfully transferred. But no file I can see uploaded (using the Azure Porta)

Comment: ok sorry. Now files are there. It was a long refresh glitch of Azure. So it seems to work. many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to issue '**No SAS token or OAuth token is present**' is to run the keyctl session workaround Session. This issue was identified and the keyctl work around can be found here - **Azcopy login/logout fails**
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/452